# Spring Boot deleteAll method response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have the following deleteAll method implementation:

***Controller***

```
@DeleteMapping("/employees")
public ResponseEntity deleteAll() {
    employeeService.deleteAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(SUCCESSFULLY_DELETED);
}
```

***Service***

```
public void deleteAll() {
    employeeRepository.deleteAll();
}
```

When I analyze the code, I get "Provide the parametrized type for this generic" error. I think I should return some object, but as I delete all the record, I am not sure what is the proper way. For delete, I generally return the id of deleted record and I thought to return id list of the deleted records for `deleteAll()` method, but not sure. So;

What should I return for `delete()` and `deleteAll()` methods in Spring Boot? Could you post a proper controller and service method examples?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: What DO you want to return? If we do not want to return anything, using `ResponseEntity.noContent().build()` and a return-type of `ResponseEntity<?>` is a legal option. If we just want to return a `String` we can set the return-type to `ResponseEntity<String>`.

Comment: what is the type of variable/enum SUCCESSFULLY_DELETED ?

Comment: @HamzaHathoute `SUCCESSFULLY_DELETED` is a constant string, not important. I am just wondering what would you return for delete  and deleteAll methods. Normally I return `ResponseEntity<T>`, for example to get a single record I return `ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto>`.

Comment: @Turing85 I am just wondering what would you return for delete  and deleteAll methods. Normally I return `ResponseEntity<T>`, for example to get a single record I return `ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto>`.

Comment: @SpeedyGozales Did you read the question? You may re-read again slowly

Comment: @diana A `204 NO CONTENT` seems appropiate. I tend to return the deleted entity on a single-delete. For a collection-delete, however, this might be too expensive.

Comment: @diana Since it is a String, you are returning a ResponseEntity<String>.
What I would suggest is to just return a status code (`200 OK` for example) to denote that you have successfully deleted all fields.

Comment: @Turing85 In this scene, for single record deletion returning id seems good. For deleting all the records, maybe just a message may be displayed. What do you think?

Comment: I do not see any benefit of a message. The status code on its own already conveys that all entries were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, I can see that `SUCCESSFULLY_DELETED` is a string, therefore returning a `ResponseEntity<String>`. You could just edit the return type of the method to suppress the warning.

Personally, what I would have done is to return an Status Code (`200 OK` or `204 NO CONTENT` as @Turing85 suggested) to denote that the operation completed successfully, without returning any object. If something went wrong then just return a server error code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes `ResponseEntity<String>` fixed error. However, I could not imagine the second paragraph. Could you please post example code for Service and Controller in each case? Thanks in advance and voted up.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but cannot vote up :(

Comment: The way you would do it here is to make this method `void` and annotate it with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)`. This means that if the method terminates successfully (ie: the service does not throw an exception), Spring will return a `200 OK`, and the client will know that the operation was successful.

Comment: If something is wrong, spring will automatically return a `500 Internal Server Error`. You just have to handle this case from the client.

Comment: Yeah, I handle all of the exceptions via custom exceptionHandler using `@ConterollerAdvice`. Thanks a lot.